# How to Add Reactivity to Dynamically Created Plots From Dynamically Created sliderInputs?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm sorry my code is too complex to create a MRE. I am currently trying to dynamically output n numbers of plots & inputSliders based on the number of calculation columns inputted. I have looked almost everywhere, however I can not seem to find a previously posted question that connects dynamically produced plots & sliders.

**Goals:**
 Upload n plots & inputSlider based up a file upload.
 Two reactive vertical lines on top of the plot that move based on the respective inputSlider range.

**What actually happens:** The correct number of plots & sliderInputs output, however the inputSliders aren't reactive to the created plots AND the vertical line doesn't appear.

I don't receive any error messages, however I am almost certain that the issues lies in that my **inputSlider information returns NULL**.

I've tried to change the possible inputs for the ggplot code to hopefully show the respective plots by doing:

```
...+geom_vline(xintercept = input$plotSlider[1])+ geom_vline(xintercept = input$plotSlider[2])

...+geom_vline(xintercept = output$plotSlider[1])+geom_vline(xintercept = output$plotSlider[2])

..+geom_vline(xintercept = plotSlider[1]) +geom_vline(xintercept = plotSlider[2])
```

I also have tried rendering the sliders before the plots, since the input variable wouldn't have been created yet.

This here is a sample csv file:

```
structure(list(X10.9 = c(11.1, 11.6, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.4), X = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.0.095 = c(-0.0911, -0.07, -0.0891, -0.1021, 
-0.1019, -0.1019), X.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X1.4241 = c(1.4396, 
1.4439, 1.4454, 1.4498, 1.4513, 1.4513), X.2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), X1.4353 = c(1.4498, 1.4648, 1.474, 1.4819, 1.485, 
1.4866), X.3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X0.6736 = c(0.6943, 
0.7066, 0.7141, 0.7179, 0.7193, 0.7182)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

My Code so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
#library(MeltR)
library(shiny)
library(glue)

# Define UI ----
ui <- navbarPage(title = "MeltShiny",
                 id = "navbar",
                 navbarMenu("File",
                            tabPanel("Add Data", 
                                     fluidPage(
                                       sidebarLayout(
                                         sidebarPanel(
                                           textInput(label="Enter the Pathlength for each Absorbance Reading(separated by commas)",
                                                     placeholder = "E.g: 2,5,3,2,...",
                                                     inputId = "pathlengths"),
                                           fileInput(label = "Add Data",
                                                     inputId = "inputFile",
                                                     multiple = FALSE,
                                                     accept = ".csv")
                                         ),
                                         mainPanel(
                                           tableOutput("contents")
                                         )
                                       )
                                     )
                            )
                 ),tabPanel(
                   value = "vizPanel",
                   title = "Data Visualization",
                   uiOutput("sliders"),
                   uiOutput("plots")
              
             
                 )
)      

server <- function(input,output){
  #Reactive list variable 
  values <- reactiveValues(masterFrame=NULL,up=NULL,loaded=NULL)
  plots <- reactiveValues()
  #Upload Project File
  upload <- observeEvent(eventExpr =input$inputFile,
                         handlerExpr = {
                           req(input$inputFile)
                           #Declaring variables
                           pathlengths <- c(unlist(strsplit(input$pathlengths,",")))
                           req(input$inputFile)
                           fileName = input$inputFile$datapath
                           cd <- read.csv(file = fileName,header=FALSE)
                           df <- cd %>% select_if(~ !any(is.na(.)))
                           #Creating temporary frame to store sample data
                           columns <- c("Sample", "Pathlength", "Temperature", "Absorbance")
                           tempFrame <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 4))
                           colnames(tempFrame) <- columns
                           readings <- ncol(df)
                           #Loop that appends sample data 
                           counter <- 1
                           for (x in 2:readings){
                             col <- df[x]
                             sample<-rep(c(counter),times=nrow(df[x]))
                             pathlength<-rep(c(pathlengths[counter]),times=nrow(df[x]))
                             col <- df[x]
                             t <- data.frame(sample,pathlength,df[1],df[x])
                             names(t) <- names(tempFrame)
                             tempFrame <- rbind(tempFrame, t)
                             counter <- counter + 1
                           }
                           values$numReadings <- counter-1
                           values$masterFrame <- tempFrame
                           values$up <- 1
                         }
  )
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    return(values$masterFrame)})
  

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$navbar == "vizPanel",
               handlerExpr = {
                 req(input$inputFile)
                 print("Observe Triggered")
                 for(i in 1:values$numReadings){
                   local({
                     myI <- i 
                     plotName = paste0("plot",myI)
                     plotSlider = paste0("plotSlider",myI)
                     output[[plotName]] <- renderPlot({
                       data = values$masterFrame[values$masterFrame$Sample == myI,]
                       ggplot(data, aes(x = Temperature, 
                                        y = Absorbance, 
                                        color = factor(Sample))) +geom_point() +theme_classic()+geom_vline(xintercept = input$plotSlider[1]) +geom_vline(xintercept = input$plotSlider[2])
                     })
                   })
                   values$loaded <- 1
                   }
                 }
               )
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    req(values$loaded)
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:values$numReadings, function(i){
      plotName <- paste0("plot",i)
      plotOutput(plotName,height=280,width=250)
    })
    do.call(tagList,plot_output_list)
  })
  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    req(input$inputFile)
    print("slider")
    slider_output_list <- lapply(1:values$numReadings, function(i){
      plotSlider <- paste0("plotSlider",i)
      data = values$masterFrame[values$masterFrame$Sample == i,]
      xmin = min(data$Temperature)
      xmax = max(data$Temperature)
      sliderInput(plotSlider,"Range of values",min=xmin,max=xmax,value=c(xmin,xmax))
    })
    do.call(tagList,slider_output_list)
  })

}
# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appropriate syntax for `input$plotSlider` will make it work.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
#library(MeltR)
library(shiny)
library(glue)

# Define UI ----
ui <- navbarPage(title = "MeltShiny",
                 id = "navbar",
                 navbarMenu("File",
                            tabPanel("Add Data", 
                                     fluidPage(
                                       sidebarLayout(
                                         sidebarPanel(
                                           textInput(label="Enter the Pathlength for each Absorbance Reading(separated by commas)",
                                                     placeholder = "E.g: 2,5,3,2,...",
                                                     inputId = "pathlengths"),
                                           fileInput(label = "Add Data",
                                                     inputId = "inputFile",
                                                     multiple = FALSE,
                                                     accept = ".csv")
                                         ),
                                         mainPanel(
                                           tableOutput("contents")
                                         )
                                       )
                                     )
                            )
                 ),tabPanel(
                   value = "vizPanel",
                   title = "Data Visualization",
                   uiOutput("sliders"),
                   uiOutput("plots")
                   
                   
                 )
)     

server <- function(input,output){
  #Reactive list variable 
  values <- reactiveValues(masterFrame=NULL,up=NULL,loaded=NULL)
  plots <- reactiveValues()
  #Upload Project File
  upload <- observeEvent(eventExpr =input$inputFile,
                         handlerExpr = {
                           req(input$inputFile)
                           #Declaring variables
                           pathlengths <- c(unlist(strsplit(input$pathlengths,",")))
                           req(input$inputFile)
                           fileName = input$inputFile$datapath
                           cd <- read.csv(file = fileName,header=TRUE)
                           df <- cd %>% select_if(~ !any(is.na(.)))
                           
                           #Creating temporary frame to store sample data
                           columns <- c("Sample", "Pathlength", "Temperature", "Absorbance")
                           tempFrame <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 4))
                           colnames(tempFrame) <- columns
                           readings <- ncol(df)
                           #Loop that appends sample data 
                           counter <- 1
                           for (x in 2:readings){
                             # local({
                             #   x <- x
                               col <- df[x]
                               sample<-rep(c(counter),times=nrow(df[x]))
                               pathlength<-rep(c(pathlengths[counter]),times=nrow(df[x]))
                               col <- df[x]
                               t <- data.frame(sample,pathlength,df[1],df[x])
                               names(t) <- names(tempFrame)
                               tempFrame <- rbind(tempFrame, t)
                               counter <- counter + 1
                             #})
                             
                           }
                           values$numReadings <- counter-1
                           values$masterFrame <- tempFrame
                           values$up <- 1
                         }
  )
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    return(values$masterFrame)})
 
  
  # observeEvent(eventExpr = input$navbar == "vizPanel",
  #              handlerExpr = {
  observe({
                 req(input$inputFile)
                 #print(input[[paste0("plotSlider1")]])
                 print("Observe Triggered")
                 for(i in 1:values$numReadings){
                   local({
                     myI <- i 
                     plotName = paste0("plot",myI)
                     plotSlider = paste0("plotSlider",myI)
                     output[[plotName]] <- renderPlot({
                       data = values$masterFrame[values$masterFrame$Sample == myI,]
                       ggplot(data, aes(x = Temperature, 
                                        y = Absorbance, 
                                        color = factor(Sample))) +
                         geom_point() + theme_classic()+
                         geom_vline(xintercept = input[[paste0("plotSlider",myI)]][1]) +
                         geom_vline(xintercept = input[[paste0("plotSlider",myI)]][2])
                     })
                   })
                   values$loaded <- 1
                 }
               })
  
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    req(values$loaded)
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:values$numReadings, function(i){
      plotName <- paste0("plot",i)
      plotOutput(plotName,height=280,width=250)
    })
    do.call(tagList,plot_output_list)
  })
  
  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    req(input$inputFile)
    
    slider_output_list <- lapply(1:values$numReadings, function(i){
      plotSlider <- paste0("plotSlider",i)
      data = values$masterFrame[values$masterFrame$Sample == i,]
      xmin = min(data$Temperature)
      xmax = max(data$Temperature)
      sliderInput(plotSlider,"Range of values",min=xmin,max=xmax,value=c(xmin,xmax))
    })
    do.call(tagList,slider_output_list)
  })
  
}
# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain why a simple observe works in this case, whereas observeEvent doesn't? Does it have to do with the constant change of slider input not being picked up when changed?

Comment: You had two issues: 1. `read.csv(file = fileName,header=FALSE)`, here it should be `header=TRUE`. 2. A simple `observe` will do as otherwise it may not react to the changes in `input$plotSlider` values. You can use `observeEvent` if you use the correct `eventExpr`, namely, `c(input$Slider1, ...,input$plotSlider4)`.